# Issue for Geocode functionality in salesforce for bulk record insertion

Tags: javascript, inline-visualforce

I want to populate the Geo location values on the contact detail page on click of save button based on the Mailing City and Mailing Postal Code.I have used inline visual force page on contact object where the calculations are being performed and the Geo location values are then being displayed in the Geo location field on the detail page. But I want this functionality to work for bulk record insertion and updation say 50000 contact records.Since I have used inline visual force page on the detail page initially when i create a record the Geo location value is not populated but when i edit and save it its populating.The problem here is because of refreshing of inline VF page. I have even tried this using call outs but there is a salesforce.com limits in call outs. So is there any possible solution for the same.

Here is the JavaScript code which i have implemented on a inline VF page on contact object.

function fetchContactRecord()
        {
         var i;

```
     getContactID();


     result = sforce.connection.query("SELECT ID,MailingCity,MailingPostalCode,Location__Latitude__s,Location__Longitude__s FROM Contact where Id = '{!Contact.Id}'");
     records = result.getArray('records');

     if(records.length>0)
     {
        getLatLng(records[0].MailingCity,records[0].MailingPostalCode); 
     }

  }

    function getLatLng(city, postalcode) 
    { 
         geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();  
         geocoder.geocode( 
         { 'address': city+' '+postalcode }, 

             function(results, status) 
             { 
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
              {
                Contact.MailingCity = city;
                Contact.MailingPostalCode = postalcode ;
                Contact.Latitude  = (results[0].geometry.location.lat()).toString();  
                Contact.Longitude = (results[0].geometry.location.lng()).toString();

              } 
              else if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS || status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.INVALID_REQUEST) 
              { 
                alert('Problem with Address'); 
              } 
              else if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) 
              { 
               alert('Google Exhausted'); 
              }  
              updateContact(); 
         }); 
    }

    function updateContact() 
    { 
     var mappedContact = new sforce.SObject('Contact');  


      mappedContact.Location__Latitude__s  = Contact.Latitude; 
      mappedContact.Location__Longitude__s = Contact.Longitude; 

     mappedContact.id = Contact.ID;          

     result = sforce.connection.update([mappedContact]);  

    }   

    $(document).ready(
     function()
     {
     // authorize();

      fetchContactRecord();
     });
```